# How to conditionally apply a template via custom Angular directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/R7E7IcJjvpAg8ddbZLNt?p=preview)</kbd>

Consider the following directive:

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('maybeLink', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      maybeLink: '=',
      maybeLinkText: '='
    },
    template: '<span>' + 
              '  <span ng-hide="maybeLink" ng-bind-html="text"></span>' +
              '  <a ng-show="maybeLink" href="#" ng-bind-html="text"></a>' +
              '</span>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.text = $scope.maybeLinkText.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    }
  }; 
});
```

The directive adds both the `<span>` and the `<a>` to the DOM (only one is visible at a time).

How could I rewrite the directive such that it will add **either `<span>` or `<a>`** to the DOM, but not both?

---

**UPDATE**

OK, I guess I could use `ng-if` like that:

```
template: '<span>' + 
          '  <span ng-if="!maybeLink" ng-bind-html="text"></span>' +
          '  <a ng-if="maybeLink" href="#" ng-bind-html="text"></a>' +
          '</span>'
```

But, how could one get rid of the surrounding `<span>` in this case?

---

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a version of the directive that uses `$compile`. It doesn't have the surrounding `<span>`, but the two way data binding doesn't work either. I'm really interested to know how to fix the two way data binding issue. Any ideas?

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HkqIQ7fkSbv2RD6JNd00?p=preview)</kbd>

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('maybeLink', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      maybeLink: '=',
      maybeLinkText: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.text = scope.maybeLinkText.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

      if (scope.maybeLink) {
        element.replaceWith($compile('<a href="#" ng-bind-html="text"></a>')(scope));
      } else {
        element.replaceWith($compile('<span ng-bind-html="text"></span>')(scope));  
      } 
    } 
  }; 
});
```

Comment: Do you still want dynamic binding, i.e. when the value of `maybeLink` changes, the other element should display? Or do you need one time rendering (if `maybeLink` is true *at the time of the rendering* show this, else show that)?

Comment: I don't really need the dynamic data binding. Does this ease the implementation?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko i edited my answer, seems work, ill add the link to Plunker

Answer (score 43):

You might be able to use a `template` **function**. According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-):

> You can specify template as a string representing the template or as a **function which takes two arguments tElement and tAttrs (described in the compile function api below) and returns a string value representing the template**.

---

```
function resolveTemplate(tElement, tAttrs) {

}

angular.module('MyApp').directive('maybeLink', function() {
  return {
    //...
    template: resolveTemplate,
    //...
  }; 
});
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution. I like it. As long as you don't need access to `scope`, of course.

Comment: This looks great. How do you annotate it so that you can use this with annotations / ng-strict-di?

Answer (score 32):

I think this is the cleanest way to inject a dynamic template based on a scope property

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('dynamic-template', function () {
  return {
    template:'<ng-include src="template"/>',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function postLink(scope) {
      scope.template = 'views/dynamic-'+scope.type+'.html';
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: I used this one and got it up and running in seconds... why so many lines of code if you can achieve something short and sweet but simple and effective.. kudos well done

Comment: Should be accepted answer. I had to add an [isolated scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object)  (see the section under `scope`) to make my directive reusable for different components, but this is the answer to the question.

Comment: There is a **huge** difference between this solution and solution calling resolveTemplate, the first one is STATIC and cannot use actual model values. This one works great. What I wasn't aware is that partial included via ng-include, has proper access to the scope. Many thanks to the author of this

Comment: This is a very nice solution! However, I would like to use `transclude: true` and then `ng-transclude` in the (dynamic) template. This does not work, angular raises an error: `Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found.` Does anybody has an idea, how to solve even this?

Answer (score 5):

I came up with the following version at the end:

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('maybeLink', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      maybeLink: '=',
      maybeLinkText: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('maybeLinkText', function(newText) {
        scope.text = newText.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
      });

      scope.$watch('maybeLink', function() {
        var newElement;

        if (scope.maybeLink) {
          newElement = $compile('<a href="#" ng-bind-html="text"></a>')(scope);
        } else {
          newElement = $compile('<span ng-bind-html="text"></span>')(scope);
        }

        element.replaceWith(newElement); // Replace the DOM
        element = newElement;            // Replace the 'element' reference
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `ng-switch`.

something like

```
 template: '<span ng-switch on="maybeLink">' + 
          '  <span ng-switch-when="http://www.yahoo.com" ng-bind-html="text"></span>' +
          '  <a ng-switch-when="http://google.com" href="#" ng-bind-html="text"></a>' +
          '</span>',
```

or

```
 template: '<span ng-switch on="maybeLink">' + 
          '  <span ng-switch-when={{maybeLink.length == 0}} ng-bind-html="text"></span>' +
          '  <a ng-switch-when={{maybeLink.length > 0}} href="#" ng-bind-html="text"></a>' +
          '</span>',
```

So this is direction

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EOg1fuOrjvAFB4NWu8aW?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-if for the same

Below is the working example

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/D01gDe9CUAkSjZiD2onU?p=preview)</kbd>

Directive Code:

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('maybeLink', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      maybeLink: '=',
      maybeLinkText: '='
    },
    template: '<span>' + 
              '  <span ng-if="!maybeLink.link" ng-bind-html="text"></span>' +
              '  <a ng-if="maybeLink.link" href="#" ng-bind-html="text"></a>' +
              '</span>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.text = $scope.maybeLinkText.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    }
  }; 
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I came up with. See the **UPDATE** above. Any idea how to get rid of the surrounding `<span>`?

Answer (score 1):

The following is a solution that provides dynamic updates. Usage:

`<a rewrite-as-span="true"></a>`

`<a rewrite-as-span="false"></a>`

`<a rewrite-as-span="yourFn()"></a>`

etc.

```
app.directive('rewriteAsSpan', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<span />',
    replace: true,

    // we transclude the element because when it gets replaced with the span
    // we want all the properties from the original element
    transclude: 'element',

    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){

      return {
        post: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude){
          var rewrittenEl, originalEl;

          transclude(scope, function(clone){
            originalEl = clone;
          });


          scope.$watch(attrs.rewriteAsSpan, function(value){
            if (value === undefined || value === true){
              if (!rewrittenEl){
                // lazy compile and cache the rewritten element
                transclude(scope, function(clone){
                  rewrittenEl = tElement;
                  rewrittenEl.html(clone.html());
                  // remove this directive because the $compile would get infinite
                  rewrittenEl.removeAttr('rewrite-as-span');
                  $compile(rewrittenEl)(scope);
                });

              }

              element.replaceWith(rewrittenEl);
              element = rewrittenEl;

            } else {
              element.replaceWith(originalEl);
              element = originalEl;
            }
          });

        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Code and specs as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kaste/8814887)