# inject HTML in a dynamic ng-include template

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive

```
...
template: <div ng-include={{model.template}} \>
...
```

Where the template is dynamic. I would like to inject additional HTML inside that template via in the directive link or compile phase. How do I go about doing so?

Comment: What do you mean by the template is dynamic? please provide an example

Comment: Meaning it changes. Now that I think of it, it is not relevant to my question. I just want to insert additional markup inside that template without modifying that template itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to return the template as a string:

```
function resolveTemplate(tElement, tAttrs) {

}

angular.module('MyApp').directive('maybeLink', function() {
  return {
    //...
    template: resolveTemplate,
    //...
  }; 
});
```

see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21105774/149060