# Angular conditional template in directive; decision based on isolate scope variable from promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

basically I try to do conditional formatting of addresses.

I did a plnkr for a visualization of the simplified problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/A5eV96H9eKIua9mJyKSL?p=preview

A directive is responsible to display the right template:

```
app.directive('tqFormatAddress', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      address:'='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      switch(scope.address.country) {
      case "de":
         scope.template = 'adress-de.html';
         break;
      case "uk":
         scope.template = 'adress-uk.html';
         break;
      }
    },
    template: '<ng-include src="template"></ng-include>',
  };
});
```

Is this the right way of doing things like this?

The next step was to integrate the code into my application. I get the data using a `$resource`:

```
$scope.ansprechpartner = this.Ansprechpartner.get({id: $routeParams.id});
```

In the view:

```
<tq-format-address address="ansprechpartner.Dienstadresse"></tq-format-address>
```

Now I get an error in the directive because the resource isn't resolved yet.

One way would be to supply the whole `ansprechpartner` to the directive:

```
<tq-format-address address="ansprechpartner.Dienstadresse" promise="ansprechpartner"></tq-format-address>
```

And then do something like this(untested demonstration code):

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      ansprechpartner.then(function () {
          switch(scope.address.country) {
          case "de":
             scope.template = 'adress-de.html';
             break;
          case "uk":
             scope.template = 'adress-uk.html';
             break;
          }
      });
    },
```

Is there be another way doing this without the promise?

Comment: why you dont want to use $watch ?

Comment: what happens if i watch and the value is already present?

Comment: @Thomas See my answer for the correct way to `$parse` and apply the expected behaviour for a passed in attribute. No need to `$watch`, when `attrs.$observe` is available to you.

Comment: 'template' can be a function, not string. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21105774/155708

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Directives - How to conditionally apply a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892793/angularjs-directives-how-to-conditionally-apply-a-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason not using `ngInclude` in this scenario.

If you don't want to work with the promise inside of you're directory, you could use an expression instead, so the template gets changed as soon as your address object does:

```
app.directive('tqFormatAddress', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      address:'='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.template = function () {
        if (scope.address && scope.address.country)
          return 'adress-' + scope.address.country + '.html';

        return '';
      };
    },
    template: '<ng-include src="template()"></ng-include>',
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `attrs.$observe`.

Like so:

```
attrs.$observe('address', function (val) {
  if (val !== undefined) {
    // call your switch function. 
  }
});
```

This because initially you'll end up with an `undefined` address.

I forked and updated your plunker, have a look and see if it helps out (try switching the `uk` 
for `de` in address2 object, and vice versa with address1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/ktVyUjqZqCVxc3bXRFti?p=preview

Comment: @naeramarth7's answer looks simpler to me. What are the advantages of your solution?

Comment: @Thomas `ng-include` creates a new scope. I've had trouble in the past that child scopes within an isolated directive has trouble with communications. I don't have a plnkr or jsBin at hand to illustrate the problem. I'd suggest you try both and evaluate which one works best for your case. Both are perfectly valid answers in their own right.